# Does DB2 support enums?

Tags: enums, db2, enumeration

does DB2 support enums? I didn't really find anything online. 
The Query doesn't work:

```
create table prototype.test(id int not null primary key, level ENUM('upper', 'lower') not null);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No** DB2 does not support ENUMS. The are some database which I am aware of which suports Enums is MySql and Postgresql but DB2 for sure **does not** support it.

Answer (score 10):

You can create a check constraint for that.

```
alter table prototype.test add constraint checklevel check (level in ('upper', 'lower'));
```

Or you can include this in the create table:

```
create table prototype.test(
 id int not null primary key,
 level varchar(5) check (level in ('upper', 'lower')
);
```